# What alternatives for reporting OSX Server Web Stats do the same job as AWStats?

Tags: macos, terminal, software-recommendation, webserver

I need a replacement tool or script to generate stats from the logfiles OSX Server generates while it runs.  I have spent way too much time on AWStats and it's had nothing but permissions issues from day 1.

Any chance anybody knows any reliable web stats packages for Mointain Lion?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software recommendation not a user problem

Comment: If you want software recommendations, you'll benefit from being explicit about what you need the software to do. In some cases, general questions work but many get closed if they look like survey or wiki projects to poll for options as opposed to solve a narrow problem.

Comment: Is it not clear?  "any reliable web stats package" seems pretty clear to me.  Is it not evident I'm looking for a web stats package?  For web stats.  The narrow problem is that I need something to analyze my web stats.  AWStats has taken up too much of my time and I wish to move elsewhere, because I can't find answers for AWStats that are sufficient.  Very clear.

Answer (score 2):

1. Sawmill -- http://www.sawmill.net
2. Advanced Web Stats -- http://www.advancedwebstats.com/

These are the only ones that I could find and recommend, since Urchin and Summary were discontinued.

### Links/Resources

1. http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?250463-Best-Mac-Server-Web-Stats-Software
2. http://sixrevisions.com/usabilityaccessibility/10-promising-free-web-analytics-tools/

   - This link details 10 great Web Stats Tools (For instance, Snoop is a Mac OS Desktop Application).

Comment: How exactly do these help a user that can't get past permissions issues while installing AWStats? Doing some searching is good, but the lack of focus in the question makes this less useful to others.

Comment: I thought that the permission issues were related only to AWStats. I'm sorry if I misunderstood the question; I thought that he was asking for software recommendation.

Comment: I am not asking about AWStats at all.  I merely indicated I was trying to make it work and it has issues.  I have spent too much time and I'm asking for recommendations from other people about other packages.  The question was indeed clear, but for some reason, this guy doesn't understand.  Sameetandpotatoes, you did not misunderstand the question.